# How do I write multiple exponents within a fraction (Anki and LaTeX)?

Tags: math-operators, fractions

I'm using Anki and LaTeX to format my flash cards. This problem that I'm about to outline only occurs with the cloze card type.

I basically want to express a fraction with multiple exponents like such `$\frac{a^{cd}}{b^{ef}}$` and I tested that this works with a basic flash card type.

However, as soon as I wrap this line in cloze deletion tags as such:

```
{{c1::$\frac{a^{cd}}{b^{ef}}$}}
```

I get errors such as "! Missing } inserted.".

Note couple of things. When i remove `{}` surrounding the exponent as such `$\frac{a^cd}{b^ef}$` it works, but obviously i get a wrong fraction. Additionally, it also works when the term is not within a fraction as such `{{c1::$a^{abc}$}}` (this works with cloze).

Editted: The whole post.

Comment: We'd need to replicate the behaviour. Can you trim down your current document into something we call a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)?

Comment: I'm not seeing a difference between "when I attempt something like ... $\frac{1}{a^{n-m}}$" which gives you errors and "$\frac{1}{a^{n-m}}$ produces an incorrect fraction" but no errors.

Comment: Teepeemm and @Werner I edited the post to show at which point exactly the error occurs.

Comment: @Vocaloidas: This seems like a mis-interpretation by Anki, thinking the double closing braces inside the `\frac` is also the closing braces for the "cloze card type", since your other examples seem to echo that. There are ways around it, but the problem seems to be Anki-related, not LaTeX-related.

Comment: I see, i guess I'll look elsewhere.

Comment: I think it must be Anki-related, as well; when I run this in LaTeX, it works.

Comment: It's 100% confirmed Anki related. As Werner pointed out the cloze tags surrounding the `\frac{a^{a}}{a^{a}}` will treat the last }} in the expression as indication to delimit the cloze deletion when in reality it should only look at the last }} tags in the overall expression.

Comment: Even if this is Anki-related, you might try `\lbrace ... \rbrace` to replace the `(...)` around the superscripts.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as @Werner described. In Anki cloze is delimited as `{{c1::}}` and in LaTeX fractions take the format of `$\frac{}{}$`. When you couple that with exponents as such `$\frac{a^{}}{b^{}}$` and wrap it in cloze tags as such `{{c1::$\frac{a^{}}{b^{}}$}}`. Anki treats the first set of `}}` as indication that it's the end of the cloze expression. This ofcourse causes the ""! Missing } inserted." errors.

The solution to this is documented in https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/manual.html#latex-conflicts (Thanks to a reddit user who pointed this out).

And simply involves putting a space inbetween the '}}' that are ought to be part of fraction's expression. This completely solves the problem.